# Android TextView: Getting "W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1. maxLines:1 lineCount:1" when setting text

Tags: android, textview

I'm setting some text on a TextView every 0.5 seconds based on a timer. Everytime, when the timer runs and the text is set, I'm getting this warning message being spammed in my console.

> W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1

XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:text="0:00" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
public void setProgress() {
    // setProgress() called every 0.5 seconds
    // Hardcoded text
    mTimeText.setText("0:05");
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you use for displaying test?

Comment: @JK Yea sorry. I just added it.

Comment: One thing is unclear for me. Why do you call `DateTimeUtils.formatTimeFromMillis(timeMs));`? Is the class containing the `formatTimeFromMillis` named `DateTimeUtils`? In the code you given it it looks like these methods are in the same class.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I removed the `DateTimeUtils` part.

Comment: I can't see any error in this code... And you can just replace formatTimeFromMillis method with hardcored string, would be much easier to read.

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, but try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754299/how-to-properly-set-line-height-for-android

Comment: @JK I solved the issue, it's a bizarre one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Answering my own question.**

Notice how I have two TextView's `title_text` and `time_text`.
Commenting out `//mTimeText.setText("0:05");` solved the issue of the warning message being spammed, so I thought the issue had to do something with `time_text`, but it didn't.

It had to do with `title_text`. Notice how I set the properties `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:ellipsize="end"`. If I had text that would overflow past the `maxLines` limit and trigger the ellipses, then I would get the warning message. Removing the line `android:ellipsize="end"` solved the issue. However, I need the ellipses, so that's not going to work.

The only other solution I could come up with is replacing `android:maxLines="1"` with `android:singleLine="true"`, however that xml property is deprecated!

Therefore, I just set `mTitleText.setSingleLine(true)` programmatically in my java code. That method isn't deprecated so I think I'm in the clear.

As to why commenting out `//mTimeText.setText("0:05");` prevented the warning message from showing up, I don't really know. I'm stumped on that one.

Comment: That's really weird - but thank you for the solution. I had this effect only on Nokia devices (Android One). Setting ``.setSingleLine(true)`` in code not only removed the warning, the UI got significantly more performant! I'd give +10 if I could :-)

Comment: Why do you say android:singleLine="true" xml is deprecated ? Adding this line to my TextView's xml description fixed the problem and it does appears as deprecated !

Comment: `maxLines="1"` doesn't show me any deprecation warning in Android Studio.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in Android which is marked as fixed, so we'll have to wait for the next patch: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121092510

Comment: Still getting this issue when layout_height = "wrap_content"

Comment: marked Won't Fix so it's not clear whether it will be fixed in the future. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Still not fixed unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

I got it solved by changing the TextView's `layout_height` configuration from `wrap_content` to `match_parent`. Defining a fixed `layout_height` is another way to solve it.

Examples:

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"` or `android:layout_height="20dp"`