# W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1. maxLines:1 lineCount:1

Tags: android, textview, staticlayout

so im getting this W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1 spamming the logs, the answer I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49416089/android-textview-getting-w-staticlayout-maxlineheight-should-not-be-1-maxli) suggests its a bug that was fixed but is still present, but wondered if anyone has a work around, the user that posted the question found it was an issue when using max lines and ellipsize but im not using either, if anyone can help I'd appreciate it, i have a view pager inside a view pager that displays a card with a bottom navigation view and some tabs (please don't question the design there is a method in this madness) here is my inner view pager layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:attrs="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/slide_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/title_guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.16" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTitleText"
      android:text="@string/choose_a_theme"
      android:textColor="@color/background_light"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/title_guideline"
      android:gravity="center"/>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:id="@+id/content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/spacer"
      android:layout_height="0dp">


      <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/pageIndicatorView"/>


      <com.rd.PageIndicatorView
        android:id="@+id/pageIndicatorView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_pager"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/sub_title_guideline"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:piv_animationType="slide"
        app:piv_dynamicCount="true"
        app:piv_interactiveAnimation="true"
        app:piv_selectedColor="@android:color/white"
        app:piv_unselectedColor="@color/accent_yellow"
        app:piv_viewPager="@id/view_pager"
        attrs:piv_padding="12dp"
        attrs:piv_radius="8dp"/>


      <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
          android:id="@+id/sub_title_guideline"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.84" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          style="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyBodyText"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sub_title_guideline"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_4dp"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_4dp"
          android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_32dp"
          android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_32dp"
          android:id="@+id/subTitle"
          android:textColor="@color/background_light"
          android:text="@string/please_choose_a_theme"/>



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <View
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:id="@+id/spacer"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is my view holder that contains a toolbar, tabs and bottom nav bar, the whole thing is essentially a dummy layout to give a user a preview of what a layout will look like given a particular theme, there is nothing in any of my styles except setting colours,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_max="@dimen/max_create_profile_card"
              app:cardElevation="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_8dp"
              app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
              android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_4dp"
              app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/background_light">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                  style="?attr/toolbarStyle"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="56dp"
                  android:id="@+id/preview_toolbar"/>

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

                    <FrameLayout
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="80dp"
                      android:id="@+id/sentence_container"
                      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                      style="?attr/tabLayoutStyle"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="56dp"
                      android:id="@+id/preview_tabs"
                      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sentence_container">

                        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="80dp"
                      android:id="@+id/space"
                      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/preview_tabs"/>

                    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                      android:id="@+id/navigation"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:background="@color/background_light"
                      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored"
                      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/space"
                      app:menu="@menu/navigation" />


                    <com.github.sealstudios.fab.FloatingActionButton
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/speak_fab"
                      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/preview_tabs"
                      android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_white_24dp"
                        app:fab_size="mini"
                      android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"/>

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

i set these attributes to my tablayout

```
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
```

and i set tab icons and text like this

```
 private void setUpMaterialTabs(String[] labels,int[] tabIcons){
    for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
      int index = i * 2;
      Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);

      if (theme.equals(Constants.THEME_YELLOW)){
        Objects.requireNonNull(tab).setIcon(tabIcons[index]);

      }else{
        Objects.requireNonNull(tab).setIcon(tabIcons[index + 1]);
      }
      tab.setText(labels[i]);
    }
    setTabTextColor(theme, getActivity());
  }
```

Comment: if i remove the call to setUpMaterialTabs i dont get the logs

Comment: ok seems to be only the call to tab.setText(labels[i]);

Comment: tried changing the string array to an int array and just giving it the string . resource id but still getting the same . problem

Answer (score 0):

ok using my own tab avoids the error

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLabels.length; i++) {
  TextView textView;
  int index = i * 2;

  if (theme.equals(Constants.THEME_YELLOW)) {
    textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
        .inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_dark, null);
    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, tabImage[index], 0, 0);
  } else {
    textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, tabImage[index + 1], 0, 0);
  }
  textView.setText(tabLabels[i]);
  tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(textView);

}
```