# Android lineHeight vs lineSpacingExtra

Tags: android, textview, styles

can I know what is the difference between lineHeight and lineSpacingExtra in android xml. I tried to compare both, but I got the different result (I need the lineHeight function, however it is only supported in API 28).

Here is part of my code:

left:

`android:textSize="14sp"`

`android:lineSpacingExtra="6dp"`

right:

`android:textSize="14sp"`

`android:lineHeight="20dp"`

Result:

[image]

Any solution for this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You mentioned you want to set `lineHeight` in pre-API 28, an alternative approach would be to just set a small `lineSpacingExtra` / `lineSpacingMultiplier` value (as you have shown). Otherwise, there are many solutions to setting a line height yourself in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754299/how-to-properly-set-line-height-for-android).

I'll briefly cover the differences below, with my summary and the official documentation.

`android:lineHeight` is the total height of each line. This includes the text, as well as any padding on the top and bottom.

> Explicit height between lines of text. If set, this will override the values set for lineSpacingExtra and lineSpacingMultiplier.

`android:lineSpacingExtra` is the *additional* spacing added after each line of text (except the last one).

> Extra spacing between lines of text. The value will not be applied for the last line of text.

Finally, you may be interested in `android:lineSpacingMultiplier`. This is similar to `lineSpacingExtra`, but with a multiplier value of the current height (e.g. `1.2`) instead of a fixed value.

> Extra spacing between lines of text, as a multiplier. The value will not be applied for the last line of text.

Further information (besides the included quotas) is available [in the TextView documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lineHeight).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. But, I don't quite understand about "Explicit height between lines of text". By the way, you mentioned that I can use my alternative approach in pre-API 28, but I got a different result for that. Any idea or calculation to get the same result as using lineHeight?

Comment: Simply the "gap" between lines of text! There's quite a few answers here already for calculating / setting it yourself in pre-API 28.

Comment: I have tried those solutions, however the result is different from the lineHeight provided in API 28.

Comment: If you really need specific line heights, there [are very good libraries](https://github.com/Actinarium/Aligned) specifically for this! Alternatively, you could mark this answer as solved (since you asked the difference between two XML parameters), then make a new one explicitly explaining your new question?

Answer (score 5):

[MaterialTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textview/MaterialTextView) (MTV) includes the ability to set the `android:lineHeight`.

And if you use the `app:` prefix, it is backwards compatible until SDK-Version 21.

Btw., under some circumstances (i believe its depending on your style, but am not sure about it), standard `TextViews` are automatically replaced with MTVs. (Check your LayoutInspector, you might already use them without knowing it)

In case you're still wondering about the differences, there's an excellent [talk by the android team](https://youtu.be/x-FcOX6ErdI?t=1010) about text in general; which should solve your question at ~16:50.

Answer (score 2):

```
android:lineHeight
```

is used to specify the total height for single line of text.

```
android:lineSpacingExtra
```

is used to add extra spacing between 2 lines of text in addition to the default line height used by android.

In order to replicate lineHeight functionality with API level < 28, set the lineSpacingMultiplier to 0 and set the lineSpacingExtra to the lineHeight that you want to use

```
android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0"
android:lineSpacingExtra="<enter line height value here in dp>"
```

Answer (score 1):

android:lineHeight defines **Explicit height between lines of text**. while android:lineSpacingExtra defines **Extra spacing between lines of text** 
you can read more [android_documentation_for_text_arributes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView)